# Question about the time complexity of recursive code for leetcode 1011

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

So I was doing the following problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/capacity-to-ship-packages-within-d-days/

I know that there is a more optimal binary search solution, but at first I thought of a recursive solution, and I wasn't quite sure about the easiest way to explain the time complexity for it.

Basically my brute force approach would be to go through all the prefixes of length D for the array (each of those represents the potential packages we could ship on day 1), and then for each of those prefixes, just recurse on the rest of the array with a decremented value of D, to figure out the minimum capacity to ship those remaining packages with D-1 days. Then the max of the sum of hte prefix and the recursive result gives me the minimum capacity corresponding to that prefix.

Then I basically have to do this for all the prefixes, and get the minimum capacity across all prefixes. The code is something like this.. I'm not sure how we derive the time complexity easily in an interview though? (There may be a bug here, i just jotted this code down quickly to illustrate the concept)

```
def shipWithinDays(weights, D):
    if D == 1:
        return sum(D)

    min_capacity = float('inf')
    capacity_till_i = 0
    for i in xrange(D):
        capacity_till_i += weights[i]
        capacity_for_remaining = shipWithinDays(weights[i+1:],D-1)

        min_capacity = min(min_capacity, max(capacity_till_i, capacity_for_remaining))

    return min_capacity
```

Now, I know we can use the "Unrolling method" taught in most algo classes to analyze this, so
if the time complexity is T(n), in my case, the recursions after the first recursive call process an array of length n - 1, n - 2, and so on to an array length of n - D. This leads to a recurrence relation like:

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) + ... + T(n-D)

Now, I can unroll the T(n-1) term, and then I would get the following
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + T(n-3) + .... + T(n-1-D)

T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n-1-D)
^ I think the above should simplify to 2^n or something right? 
I feel like this is a bit too math heavy to do especially in an interview setting, is there a more intuitive way to explain why its 2^n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a more intuitive way to explain why its 2^n?

To begin with, it is not `2^n`. It is indeed exponential, something to the nth power, but this *something* is not necessarily 2.

A bit of math: any linear recurrence relation admits a solution in form of `T(n) = a ** n`, where `a` is a root of a characteristic polynomial, in this case

```
a ** D = a ** {D-1} + a ** {D-2} + ... + 1
```

Now all you have to prove is that there is a root greater than 1, which is more or less trivial. Indeed, when `a` equals to 1, left hand side (which is 1) is less than right hand side (which is `D`). As `a` grows to infinity LHS grows faster than RHS, and eventually becomes larger. It means that there exist `a > 1` at which they are equal.

This is pretty much it. My inner math teacher would like to hear a little bit more. As an interviewer, I'd be very happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this question is a typical Binary Search. I don't think even your solution would pass the "Online Judge" because of high time complexity (which your analysis might be correct). But, you can test your solution.

In an interview setting, all they are looking for is the most efficient algorithm, which you can usually find them in the discussion panel. They don't even want to know anything about brute force algorithms, unless if maybe the question would be too hard or something.

This would probably be O(N Log N) time and constant memory:

#### Python

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def shipWithinDays(self, weights: List[int], d: int) -> int:
        lo, hi = max(weights), sum(weights)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1) # or mid = (lo + hi) // 2 || mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
            cur, required = 0, 1
            for weight in weights:
                if cur + weight > mid:
                    required += 1
                    cur = 0
                cur += weight
            if required > d:
                lo = -~mid # simply lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid

        return lo
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public int shipWithinDays(int[] weights, int d) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = 0;

        for (int weight : weights) {
            lo = Math.max(lo, weight);
            hi += weight;
        }

        while (lo < hi) {
            int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int required = 1;
            int cur = 0;

            for (int weight : weights) {
                if (cur + weight > mid) {
                    required += 1;
                    cur = 0;
                }

                cur += weight;
            }

            if (required > d)
                lo = -~mid;

            else
                hi = mid;
        }

        return lo;
    }
}
```

#### C++

```
class Solution {
public:
    int shipWithinDays(vector<int> &weights, int d) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = INT_MAX;

        for (int weight : weights)
            lo = max(lo, weight);

        while (lo < hi) {
            int mid = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int required = 1;
            int cur = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < weights.size() && required <= d; cur += weights[index++])
                if (cur + weights[index] > mid)
                    cur = 0, required++;

            if (required > d)
                lo = -~mid;

            else
                hi = mid;

        }

        return lo;
    }
};
```

---

I would suggest to focus on the **clean code** during the interview. You most likely don't need to write T(N). You can just tell to the interviewer that what your time/space complexity is. In the interview, stressing on the "big-o" is usually not a good idea, because they might have different opinions, not to mention they look for practical big-o analysis.

I would suggest to quickly pass through the bio-o part. If the interviewer would have had follow-up questions, you can just expand on it.

If your strength is bio-o, maybe you can just a bit spend time on it. It is algorithm, data structure, and system design/architecture that usually matters the most.

#### Reference

These are [lee215](https://leetcode.com/lee215/)'s solution, who by the way designs some of these LeetCode's questions, and usually posts the most efficient solutions on LeetCode's discussion panel.

[LeetCode 1011](https://leetcode.com/problems/capacity-to-ship-packages-within-d-days/)

Comment: I understand that interviewers want the most efficient solution, but I am just curious about how to analyze the time complexity properly because there may be other questions with a similar brute force solution which cannot be solved in a better way